# Processor word size? 8bit processor = 8 bit word?

Tags: c, cpu-word, atomic

I thought if I had an AVR 8 bit microcontroller the wordsize is 8 bits/1 byte? But in the datasheet it states that most AVR processors have a 16bit word. But it does not say that the specific processor has that. Weird to state something generally in a specific datasheet.

But what is the 8-bit, 32-bit MCU about if that is not the word size?

If wordsize = 2 byte then this is atomic in C right:
U16 Position;

Position = 1000;

But if the word is 1 byte I should disable interrupts (the interrupt uses this variable) when writing to this variable?
How slow is it to disable interrupts?

Comment: modern 64 bit CPUs have registers with even 256 bit wide words ( AVX registers ), there are really old 32 bit CPUs with 128 bit wide reg. ( MMX, still in use today ) . There is almost no correlation between the bitness of your CPU and how wide is the word of reference, even more, you can have different optimal sizes for your "word" when targeting different registers, MMX vs AVX it's a simple example for this, in modern CPUs you get both and they have different word-size. You should read the manufacturer documentation, it's the only thing that can tell you what you need to know.

Comment: You should read the generated code to figure this out, or (better) search for platform-specific information about atomic instructions. It's not safe to assume that e.g. a single move to RAM is atomic.

Comment: You should have a `stdint.h` file specifically for your microcontroller that `typedef`s data types so it's easier to know their bit widths.

Answer (score 6):

The traditional AVR family (i.e. ATtiny, ATmega, ATxmega, not the AVR32) are 8-bit MCUs working on 8-bit registers/accumulators, though there are a few 16-bit instructions such as when dealing with pointers through address pairs.

Unfortunately there is no universally accepted definition of what a "word" is. In this context I suspect that the author is simply referring to a 16-bit value as a word, as oppose to an 8-bit byte or a 32-bit double-word.

So, no, you cannot count on a 16-bit variable being accessed atomically. Thankfully some of the most important I/O registers, such as timers, where this matters have internal latches to hide the fact but you do need to be careful with RAM variables shared with interrupts.

Temporarily disabling interrupts is quite fast, a cycle each for the CLI/SEI instructions. One gotcha with certain compilers (ImageCraft comes to mind) is that using inline assembly like this in a function may disable optimizations so the actual cost can be somewhat higher. Consider disabling only the contentious interrupt in question to avoid this issue and to reduce latency.

Beware that unlike some other MCUs atomic bit access is normally restricted to a small subset of registers in the lowest I/O port range, typically a few PORTs and general-purpose registers.